# Newest questions screen updates

Tags: support, bug, behavior

Many times it happens that I post a question and then visit the newest questions screen on the site and realize that my question doesn't appear on that screen for as long as a couple of minutes on the screen. But the same is not the case with Stack Exchange.com. Is this status-by-design or a bug?

Answer (score 3):

This has to do with the aggressive caching mechanisms that the site uses.  Some of the earlier [podcasts](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/podcasts/) discuss details of the system.

Since there are so many more visitors to stackoverflow than chess.stackexchange the cache is rebuilt more quickly there.

I have noticed that sometimes if my question does not appear on http://chess.stackexchange.com, it *will* appear on the questions tab (https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions).